# Aligning columns with variable text length, and adding an extra column without the header?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, forest

I have a tree that I'm almost done with (thanks to help from this forum!), but a bit stuck with a few final steps. Here are the list of changes I'd like to make:

1. Get rid of the header "Versions" while maintaining the column space itself. There would just be an empty spot where the header "Versions" currently is.
2. Add a header above Choir123 Version: [T1 Guitar, T1 accordion, and a column called Option] Put a squigqly parenthesis covering the 4 rows under T1 accordion and under the header "Option," write "instrument choice", so that it's aligned in the middle.
3. Add a a column at the end of Orchestra232 Version called "Option", but a squiggly parenthesis and write "instrument price"
4. Flip the order (including header) of Choir and Orchestra so that the Choir appears first.

It would be also be really great if all the columns are aligned consistent with the header distance (currently they are dictated by the text length) and not consistent between the Orchestra and Choir Version.

Please see below for a screenshot in which I describe the changes, and the code below.

Many thanks in advance!!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{2}
\caption{Flowchart}
\medskip

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    grow'=east,
    forked edge, 
    delay={content=#1\strut}, inner ysep=2pt,
    if level=1{no edge, minimum width=28mm}{draw, if level=2{minimum width=22mm}{if level=3{minimum width=38mm}{minimum width=32mm}}}
}
[, coordinate
    [Versions, for tree={no edge, draw}[T1 guitar[T1 accordion[T2 guitar]]]
    ]
    [Orchestra232 Version, fit=rectangle
        [Brown[responsive[{Brown (N=60)}, name=A1][{Purple (N=67)}]][unresponsive[{Brown (N=74)}][{Purple (N=84)}]]]
        [Purple[responsive[{Brown (N=80)}][{Purple (N=84)}]][unresponsive[{Brown (N=84)}][{Purple (N=73)}, name=B1]]]
    ]
    [Choir123 Version, fit=rectangle, for tree={before drawing tree={y-=7mm}}
        [Brown[{responsive(N=144)}][{unresponsive(N=171)}]]
        [Purple[{responsive(N=161)}][{unresponsive(N=133)}]]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I got all the desired changes. I took the liberty to modify the code extensively. Before listing the code, some remarks on the implementation.

Given column alignment is desired within, but not between Orchestra and Choir Version, I propose each of them is typeset in a separate tree. To avoid duplicating the tree preamble, I put it in a style (`version`).

The lack of the alignment was due to some insufficient `minimum width`s. Rather than try to get the right values by hand, I wrote a style (`equal width within absolute level`) which sets the `minimum width` of the nodes in the given level to the maximum width on that level, and triggered it for each node in the header (including the empty node called `Versions` in the original code).

Style `equal width within absolute level` first uses the aggregate function `.max` to compute the maximum width (`max_x()-min_x()`) on the given level `level=#1`. It is stored into temporary register `tempdima`, whose value is then dumped on all nodes on that level; the nodes are then re-typeset (`typeset node`). All this needs to happen after the nodes have already been typeset, thus `before packing`, and in the context of the root node (`for root`) because the style is called from the header nodes.

The brace is drawn by the last item (`tikz`) in the style `version`. It uses  TikZ's decoration library. Set the amplitude to whatever you like (below, `5mm`), but don't forget to change the `xshift` of the node as well. The text of the node is given as the argument to `version`. The endpoints of the brace are computed using TikZ's construct `-|` (13.3.1 Intersections of perpendicular lines): the idea is to use the x coordinate of node option and the y coordinate of the top/bottom rightmost non-header node.  These nodes are referred to by Forest's relative node system.  For example, `!{2,first leaf}`, invoked on the phantom root, goes into the "data section" of the nodes and then to the first node without children (in the first tree, this is `responsive(N=144)`). Note that this works for any length of the header, but the assumption is that the header is one node longer than the rest of the tree.

Some other minor changes involve the following. I occasionally `for descendants` rather than `for tree`; they are almost the same, but the former does not apply the given options to the subtree root. I used `phantom` rather than `coordinate` on the invisible root node; then, it is unnecessary to e.g. specify `no edge` on the children.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{2}
\caption{Flowchart}
\medskip

\forestset{
  version/.style={
    phantom,
    for tree={
      grow'=east,
      delay={content=##1\strut},
      inner ysep=2pt,
    },
    for first={
      for tree={
        no edge,
        draw,
        equal width within absolute level/.option=level,
      },
      draw=none,
    },
    for last={
      for descendants={
        forked edge,
        draw
      },
    },
    tikz={\draw[decoration={brace,amplitude=5mm},decorate]
      (!{2,first leaf}.north -| !{1,first leaf}.west) --
      node[right,xshift=5mm,align=center]{#1}
      (!{2,last leaf}.south -| !{1,first leaf}.west);
    },
  },
  equal width within absolute level/.style={
    for root={
      before packing={
        tempdima/.max={max_x()-min_x()}{level=#1},
        for level={#1}{
          minimum width/.register=tempdima,
          typeset node,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

\begin{forest}
  version=instrument\\choice,
  [
    [[T1 guitar[T1 accordion[option]]]]
    [Choir123 Version,
      [Brown[{responsive(N=144)}][{unresponsive(N=171)}]]
      [Purple[{responsive(N=161)}][{unresponsive(N=133)}]]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\vspace{7mm}

\begin{forest}
  version=instrument\\price,
  [
    [[T1 guitar[T1 accordion[T2 guitar[option]]]]]
    [Orchestra232 Version,
      [Brown[responsive[{Brown (N=60)}, name=A1][{Purple (N=67)}]][unresponsive[{Brown (N=74)}][{Purple (N=84)}]]]
      [Purple[responsive[{Brown (N=80)}][{Purple (N=84)}]][unresponsive[{Brown (N=84)}][{Purple (N=73)}, name=B1]]]
    ]
  ]  
\end{forest}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: the result]